# fgets not running on ubuntu 12.04 but fine on windows (local)

Tags: php, linux, shell, ubuntu-12.04, fgets

I have a code in php as:

```
        header('Content-Type: text/HTML; charset=utf-8');
        header('Content-Encoding: none; ');

        $cmd = "pdf2htmlEX --process-outline 0 --fit-width 800 --fit-height 1200 --dest-dir uploaded/uploaded_files uploaded/uploaded_files_21_original/inputfile.pdf 2>&1>>data.log &"; 

        $descriptorspec = array(
                0 => array("pipe", "r"), // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
                1 => array("pipe", "w"), // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
                2 => array("pipe", "w")    // stderr is a pipe that the child will write to
        );


        $process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes, __DIR__); 
        //__DIR__ will set CWD


        if (is_resource($process)) {




            stream_set_blocking($pipes[1], FALSE);
            $s = fgets($pipes[1], 1024);
        echo $s;
        }
```

This will echo

preprocessing 0/1
preprocessing 1/1

when I execute it on wamp in windows.

However, when I run the same command on Ubuntu 12.04 Apache2. It does not echo any value. i.e. it gives a blank output in echo.

What am I missing here? Are there some config changes that I am missing?
Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should [enable error reporting](http://blog.flowl.info/2013/enable-display-php-errors/).

```
// Put these lines to the top of your script
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', true);
```

Then use the full path to the binary (even if you set the CWD):

```
/usr/bin/pdf2htmlEX
```

When you don't frequently read from `STDERR`, you should flag it write-append mode:

```
2 => array("pipe", "a") // a - append
```

It is also possible that errors are actually written to `STDERR`, read from it maybe there is a message.

I'm not sure how PHP handles the pipes when you redirect them in the command `2>&1>>data.log &`. Try with and without.

My experience is that `popen` works best (compared to all the commands available `shell_exec`, `system`, ...), I think it's worth trying `popen()` as an alternative.

Comment: I used "2>&1>>data.log &" to read the stderr and store it to data.log as there is a limit to the amount that can be in stout and was stopping the execution